# Update Elasticsearch synonym in real time

Tags: elasticsearch

Background:
For all this while, I always thought that, if there is any changes in the synonym file, you will need to reindex the whole index. Sure, if the index size is small, the process is not that slow, but the process itself is tedious and there will be down time.

So question:

1. Is my understanding wrong in this case? Means there is easier way to reflect the synonym changes for my index? Without the need to reindex.
2. There is a future requirements in which instead of updating the rules in the file manually, perhaps the changes can be made from DB or even UI instead. Can this be done? If this is possible, can enlighten or advice me on how to do this?
3. I believe this have something to do with Query or Index Time synonym expansion, with similar question arise before at here: The question, but does this still apply for current ES ver.5, 6 or even 7? As the definitive guide is way back at ver.2, so I a bit afraid that it already outdated.
4. If using query-time synonym, if I made any changes to synonym file, do I need to restart the nodes to take effect?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Re-indexing is one way of doing it.
- Yes you can get template and update it with synonyms via API.but agiain opening and closing of index is required here
- you can use file based synonyms to avoid re-indexing.

You can close the index, update the synonyms list and open the index.
updating the synonym list will not change any documents that have already been indexed. It will apply only to searches and to new or updated documents. To apply the changes to existing documents, you will need to reindex your data.
Below link can be helpful:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-open-close.html
https://sharing.luminis.eu/blog/updatable-synonyms-in-elasticsearch-bol-com/

**Synonyms** can be applied at query time and index time making a trade-off between performance and flexibility.
Pros and cons of both the approach you can read form here : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/1.x/synonyms-expand-or-contract.html#synonyms-expansion.
Using search_analyzer instead of analyzer in your mapping will make synonym analyzer be only used at search time.

**Answering your question:** (mentioned in comment).
What is the impact on "updating the synonym list will not change any documents that have already been indexed."?
 - Query time approach will pick synonyms and index time won’t.
Does it mean the new synonym won't affect all the existing doc?
 - Yes it won’t effect documents but will effect search result as per synonyms configured.
For example, I have McD in my existing doc, then I add a new synonym McD, McDonald, does it mean without reindex, this synonym won't work?
 - I believe above two QA answers this question.

For more information,please refer this article : http://bitsandbites.me/blog/2014/04/08/elasticsearch-synonyms/

Comment: Thanks for the kind reply. So here is the things that I don't understand, what is the impact on "updating the synonym list will not change any documents that have already been indexed."? Does it mean the new synonym won't affect all the existing doc? For example, I have McD in my existing doc, then I add a new synonym McD, McDonald, does it mean without reindex, this synonym won't work?

Comment: @Xonos ,I have edited the answer for your above questions,Please consider accepting the answer if it answers all your queries.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and I had accepted it. But with your explanation, it seems that even with current ES version which is version 7, query-time and index-time synonym still exist isn't it?

Comment: For version 6 its there for 7 have not tried. But elastic search mentions 
Deprecated , if they drop any feature. If they have not done it for Index types ,it means its there.

Comment: I had added one more relevant question as Q4, as I don't want to create another thread.

Comment: If you move to file based synonyms, you need to restart the nodes.